# Merging a set of nodes onto one (only in query)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am currently investigating how to model a bitemporal graph in neo4j. Unfortunately noone seems to have publicly undertaken this before.
One particular thing I am looking at is whether I can store in a new node only those values that have changed and then express a query that would merge all those values ordered by a given timestamp:

This creates the data I am playing with:

```
CREATE (:P1 {id: '1'})<-[:EXPANDS {date:5200, recorded:5100}]-(:P1Data {name:'Joe', wage: 3000})
// New data, recorded 2014-10-1 for 2015-1-1
MATCH (p:P1 {id: '1'}) CREATE (:P1Data { wage:3100 })-[:EXPANDS { date:5479, recorded: 5387}]->(p)
```

Now, I can get a history for a given point in time so far, e.g. like

```
MATCH (:P1 { id: '1' })<-[x:EXPANDS]-(d:P1Data)
WHERE x.recorded < 6000
WITH {date: x.date, data:d} as data
RETURN data
ORDER BY data.date DESC
```

What I would like to achieve is to merge the name and wage values such that I get a whole view of the data at a given point in time. The answer may also be that this is not really possible.

(PS: I say only in query, because I found a refactor function in apoc which does merge nodes, but that procedure **actually** merges and persists the node, while I would just want to query it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most things, you can do it using `REDUCE` like so:

```
MATCH (:P1 { id: '1' })<-[x:EXPANDS]-(d:P1Data)
WITH x.date AS date, d AS data
ORDER BY date
WITH COLLECT(data) AS datas
WITH REDUCE(s = {}, y IN datas| 
    {name: COALESCE(y.name, s.name),
    wage: COALESCE(y.wage, s.wage)})
AS most_recent_fields
RETURN most_recent_fields.name AS name, most_recent_fields.wage AS wage
```

You can do it in descending order instead (swap `s` and `y` inside the `COALESCE` statements if so), but there isn't really a way to shortcut processing the entire set of results from your queried time back to the start.

UPDATE: This will, of course, generate a Map and not a Node, but if you only want the properties and don't want to create a permanent record, a Map is actually better suited to your needs.

EXTENDED: If you don't want to specify which keys to use, you can do it without `REDUCE` like this instead:

```
MATCH (:P1 { id: '1' })<-[x:EXPANDS]-(d:P1Data)
WITH x.date AS date, d AS data
ORDER BY date
WITH COLLECT(data) AS datas
CREATE (t:Temp)
FOREACH(data IN datas|
    SET t += data)
DELETE t
RETURN t
```

This approach does create a node, but if you `DELETE` it right before you `RETURN` it, it won't persist at all. `+=` ensures that pre-existing properties aren't removed, only overwritten if the `data` node has existing values.

Comment: works fine, thanks. I guess you can't get around the fact that you need to explicitly name all properties you want to coalesce.

Comment: see update, if you're okay with the hackiness, you can avoid specifying keys.